# Progress spinner (progress indicator) not hiding when myListFragment.SetListShow(true)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);

        myListFragment.setListShown(true);
```

This code is in my main activity, inside a asyntask that does some Json execution.
I placed it in onPostExecute to make sure that the json finished executing.

Now when my list is loaded, the list fragment still shows that spinning indicator in the middle and never stops.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same problem and addressed it at follow:

```
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        // your code here
        setListAdapter(adapter); // write this line
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I followed a different approach and did not use ListFragment, but your answer makes sense since the adapter is set on postExecute = main thread. +1